# Is “vois comment les gens peut souffrir terrorisme” grammatically & meaningfully correct?

Tags: grammaire, sens

> Vois comment les gens peut souffrir terrorisme.

If its not correct, can you correct it for me please? And what does it mean in English?

Comment: Proof reading as such is off-topic. Please identify a source of concern in your sentence and ask a precise question about that.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost correct:

> Vois comment les gens peuvent souffrir du terrorisme

But *regarder* is more appropriate to your situation:

> Regarde comment les gens peuvent souffrir du terrorisme

In English, it means:

> Look/see/observe how people can suffer of terrorism

Comment: L'usage peut sembler désuet mais je préfère la version originale avec « Vois ». Il y a une notion d'ouvrir les yeux, de retirer un masque. « Regarde » implique qu'on le sait déjà mais qu'on veut plus de détails alors que la vérité dans ce contexte est qu'on détourne généralement le regard pour oublier. Il y a aussi une notion un peu idiomatique dans cette tournure (« Vois comme le monde est beau. », ou plutôt laid ici). « Vois » sonne mieux suivi de « comme ». Niveau anglais, « _see_ » ne me semble approprié que pour la version avec « vois » (avec justement la nuance entre voir et regarder).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should tell what you intend to express as your sentence might be corrected in two ways, each one with a different meaning:

> Regarde comment les gens peuvent souffrir du terrorisme.

Look at how people can suffer from terrorism (neutral: i.e. observe the way they suffer from terrorism.)

> Regarde comme les gens peuvent souffrir du terrorisme.

Look how people can suffer from terrorism (sympathy: i.e. pay attention to how much terrorism is affecting them.)

Comment: [Même commentaire que sur la réponse de Begueradj.](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/is-this-sentence-grammatically-meaningfully-correct#comment31016_16606)

Comment: @Chop « Vois » est effectivement plus littéraire mais on n'a aucune idée du niveau de langue ou même de ce que l'auteur de la question souhaite précisément exprimer puisqu'il ne semble même pas le savoir lui-même...